# How to go back to android home screen in react native

Tags: android, react-native, back

Here I don't mean the home screen of my navigator..I actually wanted to create a button which takes me to the home screen of my android device. How can i achieve this in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find the answer here in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler)
you can use

```
BackHandler.exitApp()
```